# Multithreading with Embedded ObjectDB

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa, objectdb

I need to have a atomic counter with ObjectDB but the following code doesn't work as I expected:

```
    final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test.odb");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Point p = new Point(0, 0);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(p);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    final CountDownLatch l = new CountDownLatch(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
                em.getTransaction().begin();
                //Query q = em.createQuery("UPDATE Point SET x = x + 1");
                Query query = em.createQuery("UPDATE Point SET x = x + 1");
                query.executeUpdate();
                em.getTransaction().commit();
                em.close();
                l.countDown();                    
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
    l.await();
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    TypedQuery<Point> myquery = em.createQuery("SELECT p from Point p", Point.class);
    List<Point> results = myquery.getResultList();
    System.out.println("X coordiate is: " + results.get(0).getX());
    em.close();
```

It should have printed out X coordinate is 100. But in reality, it doesn't.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your code by one of the following ways:

Synchronize your update queries, so they will be executed sequently, rather than concurrently:

```
synchronized (lock) {
    em.createQuery("UPDATE Point SET x = x + 1").executeUpdate();
}
```

Your lock object must be one object that is shared by all the threads.

Or, use ObjectDB / JPA locking, by setting a pessimistic locking timeout, e.g. by:

```
Map<String, Integer> properties =
    Collections.singletonMap("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", 1000);
EntityManagerFactory emf =
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
        "objectdb:$objectdb/db/test.tmp;drop", properties);
```

and then replacing the UPDATE query with a retrieval with a lock and an update:

```
Point point = em.find(Point.class, 1, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
point.setX(point.getX() + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better create a DAO class for Point and wrap the `persist()`, `merge()` ... functions with `synchronized` functions instead.

Alternatively an `AtomicInteger` with `getAndIncrement()` should solve your problem without the need for synchronization and locks.